# How to determine if a string exists in a file?

Tags: python

I am making a program where there will be a specific topic and the user needs to guess. The game is like a family feud. I have a text file which contains the possible answers. I am having a problem where if I input only 1 char, it will print the first condition

```
import os
f = open('D:/VB/Prog/topic1.txt')
for i in range(0,10):
    answer = input(str(i + 1) + '. ').upper()
    if answer in f.read():
        print("found")
    else:
        print("not found")
        break
```

For example, I input `'A'`. In my text file, I have this word `'Alone'`, obviously this character isn't a word and therefore should be not found – but it is saying that it is found.

An example of my answers file `topic1.txt`:

```
SPIDERS
BEING ALONE
ALONE
```

Comment: `'A' in 'Alone'` is true tho

Comment: in what format the words are there in you file? can you show us a sample of your file?

Comment: I edited my post. That's the sample

Comment: if a single word takes a whole line in your file then try `if f'{answer}\n' in f.read():`

Comment: This is working! May I know what is the meaning of f?

Comment: it is used to make a formatted string, you can do the same string like `answer + '\n'` which gives the same result as `f'{answer}\n'`

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to prepare a set of answers you are expecting, and check if the cleaned up input is within the set. Then you could also debug both parts separately, by checking whether you have parsed the answer list correctly, as well as whether you read the input as expected.

Something along the lines of the below snippet seems to do the job for me (not tested in depth!)

```python
with open('/tmp/topic1.txt') as f:
    answers = {line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()}

for i in range(0, 10):
    answer = input(str(i + 1) + '. ').upper().strip()
    if answer in answers:
        print("found")
    else:
        print("not found")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search for whole words – but your program thinks you are searching for characters. The character `"A"` is indeed contained in your answers file. Instead, you want to modify your code to search for whole words.

Here's how you might do that:

```py
with open('D:/VB/Prog/topic1.txt', 'r') as f:
    # Split by newline characters to create a list of all words
    data = f.read().split('\n')

# Convert to lowercase (or do other similar transformations)
data = [x.strip().lower() for x in data]

# Now, check if your character(s) are in the list:
for x in ['A', 'Alone']:
    if x.lower() in data:
       print(f'\"{x}\" is indeed an answer')
    else:
       print(f'\"{x}\" is NOT an answer')
```

Comment: btw, `f.read().split('\n')` -> `f.splitlines()`

Answer (score 0):

You should do it under a function:

```
def is_string_in_file(path, string):
    for line in open(path).read().split("\n"):
        for word in line.split(" "):
            if string == word:
                return True
    return False
```

Then you use this function inside your programm:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "test.txt")
    for i in range(0,10):
        if is_string_in_file(path, input(str(i + 1) + '. ').upper()):
            print("found")
        else:
            print("not found")
            break
```